# Match between occurrence of last slash in URL and hash

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match between two characters, specifically the last part of a url but only between the last slash (`/`) and a hash (`#`).

```
http://example.com/path/to/thing#name
```

The match should return

```
thing
```

I'm partly there now. I can either get the whole string of the last part of the url, or everything before hash (`#`) but not both.

```
/([^\/]*?.*(?=#))/
```

Please see my [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8X3Jkq/1) for testing.

Comment: It's usually easier to just [parse the URL](https://jsfiddle.net/9kj7bodg/)

Comment: You're right, but I'd like to learn to do this with regex :)

Comment: `/\/(?!.*\/)(\w+)#/`, take the first matching group?

Comment: do you need this to work if there is no # ?

Comment: @andi that would be a plus, for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close but still overthinking it. This suffices:

```
/[^\/#]+(?=#|$)/
```

– a sequence of not-`/` or `#` characters, where the next one should be `#`. You don't need to add parentheses to match it as a separate group, the match itself is correct. The final lookahead `(?=#|$)` makes it stop on either an intervening `#` or the end of the URL.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8X3Jkq/6).

Comment: I originally tried that but I didn't have a capturing group around everything.  Thank you :)

Comment: This pattern does not guarantee that the substring after the last `/` is matched, however, in the current context of an URL it may suffice.

Comment: The string will always be a url with a path so this will work.

Comment: Then posting other answers is useless. However, I'd use capturing without any lookaheads. [`/([^\/]+)#/`](https://regex101.com/r/98w5OI/1) is enough. Or, to be closer to the original topic - [`/^.*\/([^#]+)/`](https://regex101.com/r/98w5OI/2).

Comment: @bflemi3: sorry, that capturing group is actually a remnant of your original regex101 test. It seems unnecessary, though – see mine. (Edit) Hey, it also works with an explicit `$` to match non hash-ending strings.

Comment: The edit you last made to your regex no longer resolves to `thing`, but includes the hash. You're original answer was correct `([^\/]+(?=#))`.

Comment: @bflemi3: I must somehow have missed that. I've included the `#` in the first (matching) not-part and now it behaves correctly again. (I realize my continuous tinkering makes the 'this suffices' remark ... obsolete.)